# Como puedo cambiar el color de determinadas lineas de mi HTML file generado por un BASH

Tags: html, bash

Como resultado de un bash script tengo esta parte final de codigo que me genera un archivo HTML a partir de un archivo de texto. Requiero cambiar a color ROJO ciertas de sus lineas para poderlas diferenciar mas facilmente.

cat last_file.txt last_file_*.txt > Final_output.txt

```
if [ $(grep -c "about" Final_output.txt) -gt 0 ]
then

awk -F' : ' '
  BEGIN{
    print "<html><style type=\"text/css\">table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style><body><table><th>ENVIRONMENT CERTIFICATES</th>"
  }
  {
     print "<tr>"
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
       print "<td>" $i "</td>"
     print "</tr>"
  }
  END{
    print "</table></body></html>"
  }
' Final_output.txt > Certificates_$current_date.html
```

echo -e "Please check the attachment and output below to verify certificates that will expire within 30 days\n\n $(cat \Final_output.txt)" | mailx -a Certificates_$current_date.html -s "ENVIRONMENT CERTIFICATES, Certificates Expiring Soon" email@test.com
else
echo "There is no current SSL certificates that will expire within next 30 days. " |mailx -s "SSL CERTIFICATES REMAIN VALID" email@test.com

Adjunto Archivo de salida. deseo cambiar las lineas que contienen la palabra "about" a color ROJO.[image: Salida html]

Comment: Edité tu pregunta corrigiendo ortografía y el formato de código, y luego, en tu edición deshaces mis cambios, no entiendo por qué!

Comment: @jachguate, probablemente se solaparon. Entre tu versión la de él hay poco más de 30 segundos de diferencia. También hay que ver que en su edición agrego más info.

Comment: @Marcos diría que la página le tuvo que haber alertado que estaba machacando una edición, no recuerdo si lo hace, pero esperaría que lo haga, y que agregara la información adicional sobre la edición y no machacándola.

Comment: bash me da sed `printf "this line is fine\nthis line is about to expire" | sed '/\babout/{s|.*|<span style="color:red">&</span>|}'`

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar en el for

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
  do
    if [[ $string =~ "about" ]]; then  #busca about en la cadena
      echo "about encontrado en la linea" 
    print "<td>" $i "</td>"
  done
print "</tr>"
```

de esta forma podes saber si la linea tiene la palabra about